# how to align HTML positioning and inputs on P and centered text

Tags: html, css

Hello guys I actually been looking everywhere on google for this, and even youtube but no luck anywhere.

I actually came across this problem for the first time and I want to align everything in the center, which it is, but if you notice the paragraph and input text are not vertically aligned. they are crooked , but yet aligned in the center I am trying to make a perfect line for the text input and

in other words something like this

```
                  Age:           ______________
                  Year:          ______________   
                  group:         ______________
```

not the default center position like this

```
                        Age:           ______________
                      Year:          ______________   
                        group:         ______________
```

anyhow this is my css and html code

```
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>


    <div id="container">
      <h3 class="header"> Welcome to the registration form </h3>
      <div id="border"> </div>


        <div id="box">

         <p> Enter Name: <input class="in" type="text" name="name" value="${param.name}"> </p>
         <p> Enter Age: <input class="in" type="text" name="name" value="${param.name}"> </p>
         <p> Enter Address: <input class="in" type="text" name="name" value="${param.name}"> </p>
         <p> Enter phone: <input class="in" type="text" name="name" value="${param.name}"> </p>

        </div><!--box -->


    </div><!--container -->
  </body>
</html>
```

and my css

```
/* 
    Document   : style
    Created on : Jan 18, 2014, 9:53:43 AM
    Author     : will
    Description:
        Purpose of the stylesheet follows.
*/

*{
  margin: 0px;

}
body{
  background-color: black;
}




#container{
  color: black;
  margin: 50px auto;
  border: solid black 2px;
 text-align:center;
  width: 700px;
  height: 540px;
  background-image: url('http://www.kodemi.com/images/full/2013/12/20/white-background-wallpaper-image-pics-hdwallpc-White-Background-Wallpaper-Image-Pics.jpg');


}


#block{
  width: 300px;
  color: black;
  margin: 36px auto;

}



h3.header{
  color: black;
  font-size:25px;
  margin: 30px 30px 5px;

}

#border{
  width: 400px;
  border-top: solid black 1px;
  margin: auto;

}

#box p{
  margin: 20px;

}



#box input{
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Center the div they're wrapped in...

Answer (score 2):

You can add a label tag to the name of the field, set the width, and align the text right to assure all input boxes begin at the same point:

```
label {
    width: 115px;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: right;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Kiaaanabal/dQLzy/

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

U can use a table tags in place of the paragraph tags and easily align the input fields and texts can use cellspacing and cellpadding for more modification.

```
<div id="box">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Enter Name:</td>
                <td><input class="in" type="text" name="name"
                    value="${param.name}"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Enter Age:</td>
                <td><input class="in" type="text" name="name"
                    value="${param.name}"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Enter Address:</td>
                <td><input class="in" type="text" name="name"
                    value="${param.name}"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Enter phone:</td>
                <td><input class="in" type="text" name="name"
                    value="${param.name}"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
```

This may help.

Answer (score 0):

```
simple just: input name should be inside label and make some width to id box. Just copy paste code below: 

HTML CODE:

<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>


        <div id="container">
            <h3 class="header"> Welcome to the registration form </h3>
            <div id="border"> </div>


            <div id="box">

                <p> <label>Enter Name:</label> <input class="in" type="text" name="name" value="${param.name}"> </p>
                    <p><label> Enter Age:</label> <input class="in" type="text" name="name" value="${param.name}"> </p>
                        <p><label> Enter Address: </label><input class="in" type="text" name="name" value="${param.name}"> </p>
                            <p> <label>Enter phone: </label><input class="in" type="text" name="name" value="${param.name}"> </p>

                            </div><!--box -->


                        </div><!--container -->
                    </body>
                </html>

CSS CODE:

/* 
Document   : style
Created on : Jan 18, 2014, 9:53:43 AM
Author     : will
Description:
Purpose of the stylesheet follows.
*/

*{
    margin: 0px;

}
body{
    background-color: black;
}




#container{
    color: black;
    margin: 50px auto;
    border: solid black 2px;
    text-align:center;
    width: 700px;
    height: 540px;
    background-image: url('http://www.kodemi.com/images/full/2013/12/20/white-background-wallpaper-image-pics-hdwallpc-White-Background-Wallpaper-Image-Pics.jpg');


}


#block{
    width: 300px;
    color: black;
    margin: 36px auto;

}



h3.header{
    color: black;
    font-size:25px;
    margin: 30px 30px 5px;

}

#border{
    width: 400px;
    border-top: solid black 1px;
    margin: auto;

}

#box p{
    margin: 20px; text-align:left;

}

#box label { width:95px; float:left }

#box { width:300px; /* or 42% width*/  margin:0px auto; }

#box input{
    margin-left: 10px;
}
```